# Papaparse not parsing the last file

Tags: javascript, papaparse

I have a csv file with error. I want to show the error and let user select the file again and then parse it again.

But when i am re-uploading same file. It is not being parsed

Here is an code to reproduce this bug

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#file").on("change", function(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    
    Papa.parse(file, {
      header: true,
      skipEmptyLines: true,
      trimHeaders: true,
      complete: ({ data: json, errors: e }) => {
        if (e[0]) {
          console.log('failed to parse', file.name);
        } else {
          console.log('parsed', file.name);
        }
      },
      error: (e) => {
        console.log('failed to parse', file.name);
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.3.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="file">
```

And here is the GIF of the issue

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `e` is defined?

Comment: I am not able to re upload the same buggy csv. So and answer to your question is *YES*. Please see the GIF carefully you will understand

Comment: I notice your gif shows your original app.  If you run the snippet you posted, do you still observe the problem you posted?  Testing the snippet with Firefox it appears show the parse results as expected on every load.

Comment: Nevermind @user650881. I have solved this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by setting `e.target.files[0] = undefined` on any error